# Getting error "Cannot read property 'show' of null" in console when trying to show images with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you scroll to the end of [this article](http://www.brandroot.com/resources/item/45-your-company-name-the-first-step-towards-success) you'll see this list of names:

- Wowana
- Oomvy
- Exza
- Gozer
- Hentra
- Molisa
- Gizic
- Yaberi
- Anea
- Dymi
- Gibbal

Each of these list items contain an image and the link. The image associated with each `li` is hidden with CSS. I have been trying to setup some jQuery to so that the image shows when the link is rolled over.

Here is the code:

```
<li><img class="previewImage" src="http://www.brandroot.com/images/brands/gibbal.png" width="200" height="151" /><a href="names/gibbal">Gibbal</a></li>
```

And the simple jQuery I apply in the console to test:

```
$('.previewImage').show();
```

And the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of null
```

What am I overlooking? This is driving me crazy and imagine it's something very simple.

Comment: You have multiple libraries loaded. `$` is not `jQuery`, it's some other library (mooTools, maybe?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some reason, doing

```
jQuery('.previewImage')
```

worked, whereas

```
$('.previewImage')
```

is null. This might be caused by another library using the $ shortcut (prototype perhaps?). Long story short: use the first Syntax instead of $

Comment: Oh hey guess what I found: `function $(id) {return document.getElementById(id);}` It's in http://brandroot.com/templates/brandroot/js/select2css.js.

Comment: Yup. It's in select2css.js. WTF, I don't remember select2 breaking jQuery ever. **Facepalm** it's not the combobox select2 lib. It's a js to css selector. Not needed since jQuery brings sizzle to the table.